# Can Blazor WebAssembly call another WASM module directly?

Tags: c#, opencv, blazor, webassembly

Can Blazor WebAssembly code call functions from another WASM module directly or is a JavaScript bridge required?

OpenCV has been built for WASM, as OpenCV.js. Is there a way of exporting the function definitions from the OpenCV WASM implementation and using them directly from the Blazor code? Is the best alternative to use JS Interop and have JS functions that call the OpenCV functions?

Comment: is the WebAssembly is single file or two different file ?

Comment: The WebAssembly stuff comes down in to parts: the Blazor part first and then the OpenCV part comes down with the OpenCV.js file.

Comment: Theoretically you can run wasm modules from .NET using wasmtime .NET. Not sure if it works from a blazor app though or if it can load a wasm module as url resource.

Comment: Let's say that I have normal blazor app and additionally I have my own `file.wasm`. How can I call it from C#?

Comment: @Axelly you might be able to, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#native-dependencies-support

Answer (score 4):

This should be achieved much more easily with .NET 6 as Blazor now supports native dependencies. You can compile the OpenCV C++ or OpenCV.js to `wasm` using `emscripten` and add a native file to your `csproj` as shown below.

```
<NativeFileReference Include="path-to-output-file" />
```

You can then go ahead and P/Invoke into the native code. In this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kesUNeBZ1Os), Steve Sanderson demos a very similar scenario. You can also check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-native-dependencies?view=aspnetcore-6.0) on Native Dependencies in Blazor for more information.